# Count number array python

Tags: python, arrays, count

Here is an array in python:

```
T = np.array([[1,1,2],[2,1,1],[3,3,3]])

print np.where(T==1)
```

I want to find the number of appearance of each element. I tried to use `np.where` and then `len(np.where)`. However the output of `np.where` doesn't allow to use the `len()` function.

Comment: was any of these answers useful for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

use `numpy.unique`, it returns both the unique values and the number of appearances in the array. The method has a flag called `return_counts` which is default value is `false` like this:

`uniqueVals, count = numpy.unique(T, return_counts = true)`

Comment: `numpy.unique` will work without `reshape`, but what parameter do you pass to get the number of appearances?

Comment: @Akavall `return_counts = true`

Comment: Ahh. Nice! Maybe you should include that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following to show the number of times that the element 1 is repeated in the array `T`:

```
>>> (T == 1).sum()
4
>>> (T == 2).sum()
2
```

Answer (score 0):

If range of your integers in the array is small you can use `np.bincount`

```
In [25]: T = np.array([[1,1,2],[2,1,1],[3,3,3]])

In [26]: np.bincount(T.reshape(-1))
Out[26]: array([0, 4, 2, 3])  # 0 showed up 0 times
                              # 1 showed up 4 times
                              # 2 showed up 2 times ...
```